# How to add a logo on top left of my screen

Tags: flutter

[[image]]

Please I am a beginner in flutter and I want to add a logo on top of my screen in the image shown below.
Secondly how do I identify background colors and how do I place the text in middle of the screen. Thank you.

I tried adding a appbar but the position of the logo was in different position and the colors too i was not able to identify the colors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
          ),
          //Your other widget
        ],
      ),
```

Stack could be one of the options to achieve that, however you can use Appbar as well to achieve the same.

THe code for the elevated Button

```
SizedBox(
           width: double.maxFinite,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  child: Text('Button'),
                                  onPressed: null,
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                      side: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                          BorderSide(
                                              width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
                                      backgroundColor:
                                          MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                              Colors.transparent),
                                      padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                          EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                          TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: Please what about the background colors how do implement it and the text.

Comment: In scaffold widget there is a backgroundColor property, use that to provide color.it will give background color for your whole screen

Comment: Please how can I reduce the width size in text field.

Comment: wrap the textfield with padding

Comment: Kindly help me with the Elevated button.

Comment: what help in Elevated Button??

Comment: I attached an image to the question that I asked.

Comment: I have added the code for elevated button

Comment: Please check your code the image has border radius on the sides how can I add it.